# Is there a way to iterate through the list of mime types registered on a website?

Tags: asp.net, iis

Is there a way to iterate through the list of mime types registered on a website?

Comment: http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/staticContent/mimeMap

Comment: @Jaroslav: put you link in answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For IIS7+ you can use the [ServerManager](http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/staticContent/mimeMap).
For IIS6 there is [MimeMap Metabase Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc778002.aspx).

Bear in mind that you can allow different MIME types for specific directories.

Answer (score 0):

In Linux Ubuntu Apache2

Mime types are handled by two configuration files

- /etc/mime.types

  - is a system wide mime configuration file which if I understand correctly is used by apache.
- /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/mime.conf

  - Points to above but also contains specific configuration for that particular installation.